# Why do I have 2 connections when im using 1 client?

Tags: postgresql, connections, pgadmin-4

The command:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity
```

shows all currently active connections.
The database is hosted by AWS RDS and I am accessing the database with pgAdmin 4, thus I expect one other connection than mine and that is the rdsadmin, but it seems like I have 2 connections.

Output:
[image]

Why do I have two connections when using one Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second connection gets started when you start the query tool.